# Is it possible to obtain a sine wave with a 3 phase inverter?

Tags: inverter, three-phase, high-power

In several pages, I have read that it is possible to obtain a sine wave (maybe with harmonics) from a three-phase inverter, with six transistors or thyristors, like this:

[image: 3-phase inverter]

I have seen some techniques, like SPWM, but I am not sure about the correct working of those techniques.

I would like to know if it's possible to obtain sine waves from such inverter.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As in a pure sine wave.  No.  DC'esque sine wave.

Comment: 80% of your image is white space. Can you not crop it so it becomes legible?

Comment: If switching time is fast, inductors La/b/c are large, a decent load is present, and a the controller monitors output voltage, what will be output should *resemble* a sine wave. Depending on the capabilities of the controller.

Comment: It is possible, and with good ThD, but you need a sine filter

Comment: Yes absolutely.  An inverter made to produce a true sine wave is called a pure sine wave inverter.  3 phase has nothing to do with it.  A 3 phase inverter produces 3 sine waves 120 degrees apart from eachother.  If you want a split sine wave with a grounded neutral, an H bridge inverter is better than the type you have shown.